# AdjustResize not working For Second EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-scrollview, android-keypad

i have Two EditText in login page.Only one visible at first Time.when we open the Activity request focus to first EditText and next button Comes below EditText.When we Click next button Second Edittext will be Visible.button is not Showing below the Second EditText.it hiding the Second Edittext. i want to show below the Second Editext 
here is my Code :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.valai.school.activities.LogInActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_login"
            style="@style/Toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/signInBtnText"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_title_login"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/imgLogo"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user_name_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user_name_24dp"
                android:hint="@string/userNameHint"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtUserName"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password_24dp"
                android:hint="@string/passwordHint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupLogInAs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/login_as"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioBtnAdmin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/adminText"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioBtnParent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/parentText"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioBtnTeacher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/teacherText"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/nextBtnText"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

Comment: Test case Use **`android:fillViewport="true"`** in your `ScrollView`

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnSignIn"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_login"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_title_login"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="EDT1"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtUserName"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="EDT2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroupLogInAs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Login as"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioBtnAdmin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="Admin Text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioBtnParent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Parent Text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioBtnTeacher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="Teacher Text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Next Button Text"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_above="@id/btnSignIn" No Resource Found

Comment: I didn't get such error. btnSignIn exists and is at the end.

Comment: but btnSignIn will execute After ScrollView Right so it will not find

Comment: Thanks Man It's Working dnt knw why it was showing error

Comment: You're Welcome.